# Overriding a UIButton using Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a question about Cross platform developing using Xamarin.

I already got how Custom Rendering works in general.

Now I want to override an element of the type UI button:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomButton), typeof(CustomButtonRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.iOS.CustomRendering
{
    public class CustomButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(255,255,255);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine, BUT the Control object does not have all properties I need? For example, it doesn't provide the possiblity to set borders.

I already understood how to override the Button design on my Android project by using XML-Files. What is the iOS equivalent? Or: How do I get "full access" to design the Forms element?

Comment: Are you asking how to override all the UIButton or why you don't see the same properties you see on Android? I'm not sure about the question, maybe due to my poor English.

Comment: Yes, I only want to override all the UIButton. But I don't know the proper way.